# Sharepoint 2010 Content Organiser Rule to move to external Drop Off Library

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint-2010, ecm

Wondered if it's possible to have documents which land in the Drop Off library say of Site A and for them to be moved to the Drop Off Library of Site B.  Thing here is that Site A and Site B are both on different site collections with unique URLs.

Any help much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be achieved. You can set up a chain of Record Routing/Drop Off libraries.

Comment: Hi Wictor - thanks for the quick reply.  Would it be possible to give an example or steps to work from? Thanks